# Populate recycler view with new list if items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am fetching the data from local database and populate it on recycler view,[image]

In my application i have 3 radio button, if i click on "Direct dialing" option, the data corresponding to that populate in card view, and same for other options. But problem is that when i click to another option, It populate the data which i want but application crashes with IndexOutOfBound Exception.
My Code is :

DI.java (Where i am populating recycler view)

```
gdone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            mDatasetTypes.clear();
            source.clear();
            mDatasetTypes.clear();
            example.clear();

            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(i);
            if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Budget\nDialing")) {
              /*  Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(intent);*/


                cquery = sql.rawQuery("select BD_Mobile,BD_landline,BD_Mobile_Example,BD_landline_Example from DialingInstruction where SimId='" + substr + "'", null);

                for (cquery.moveToFirst(); !cquery.isAfterLast(); cquery.moveToNext()) {
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(0).toString());
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(1).toString());

                    source.add("Mobile");
                    source.add("Landline");

                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);

                    example.add(cquery.getString(2).toString());
                    example.add(cquery.getString(3).toString());

                }
              //  mAdapter = new InstructionAdapter(source,mDataset,example, mDatasetTypes);
                try{

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                catch(Exception e){ Log.e("tagag","caught you");}

            }
            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Prefix\nDialing")) {
                cquery = sql.rawQuery("select PD_Mobile_International,PD_landline_International,PD_Mobile_International_Example,PD_landline_International_Example from DialingInstruction where SimId='" + substr + "'", null);
                for (cquery.moveToFirst(); !cquery.isAfterLast(); cquery.moveToNext()) {
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(0).toString());
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(1).toString());

                    source.add("Mobile");
                    source.add("Landline");

                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);

                    example.add(cquery.getString(2).toString());
                    example.add(cquery.getString(3).toString());

                }
            }
            else if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Direct\nDialing"))
            {
                cquery = sql.rawQuery("select DD_Mobile_Local,DD_landline_Local,DD_Mobile_International,DD_landline_International,DD_Mobile_Local_Example,DD_landline_Local_Example,DD_Mobile_International_Example,DD_landline_International_Example from DialingInstruction where SimId='"+substr +"'", null);
                for(cquery.moveToFirst();!cquery.isAfterLast();cquery.moveToNext())
                {
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(0).toString());
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(1).toString());
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(2).toString());
                    mDataset.add(cquery.getString(3).toString());
                    source.add("Mobile(Local)");
                    source.add("Landline(Local)");
                    source.add("Mobile(International)");
                    source.add("Landline(International)");
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    mDatasetTypes.add(INSTRUCTION);
                    example.add(cquery.getString(4).toString());
                    example.add(cquery.getString(5).toString());
                    example.add(cquery.getString(6).toString());
                    example.add(cquery.getString(7).toString());
                }


            }

        }
    });
    Log.e("TAGkhj", "onCreateView: "+mDataset.size() );
    mAdapter = new InstructionAdapter(source,mDataset,example, mDatasetTypes);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter   );
    return view;
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class InstructionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InstructionAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> mSource;
private List<String> mExample;
private List<String> mDataSet;
private List<Integer> mDataSetTypes;
public static final int INSTRUCTION = 0;



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}

public class InstructionViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    TextView Ins, Detail;
    RadioButton Instruction, Exm;
    RadioGroup GroupI;
    public InstructionViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.Ins = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ins);
        this.Detail=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        this.Instruction=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.instruction);
        this.Exm=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.exm);
        this.GroupI=(RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.groupI);
    }
}
public InstructionAdapter(List<String> source, List<String> dataSet, List<String> example, List<Integer> dataSetTypes) {
 mSource=null;
    mExample=null;
    mDataSet=null;
    mDataSetTypes=null;

    mDataSet = dataSet;
    mDataSetTypes = dataSetTypes;
    mSource=source;
    mExample=example;
    try {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("lfkjdlg", "InstructionAdapter: ");
    }

}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    if (viewType == INSTRUCTION) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.instructionxml, parent, false);

        return new InstructionViewHolder(v);
    }
    else
        return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == INSTRUCTION) {
        final InstructionViewHolder instructionViewHolder = (InstructionViewHolder) holder;
        instructionViewHolder.Ins.setText(mSource.get(position));
        int SelId=instructionViewHolder.GroupI.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) instructionViewHolder.GroupI.findViewById(SelId);
        if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Instruction"))
        {
            instructionViewHolder.Detail.setText(mDataSet.get(position));
        }
        instructionViewHolder.GroupI.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(i);
                if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Example"))
                {
                    instructionViewHolder.Detail.setText(mExample.get(position));
                }
                else {
                    instructionViewHolder.Detail.setText(mDataSet.get(position));

                }
            }
        });
        //  holder.temp.setText(mDataSet[position]);
    }
   /* mDataSet.clear();
    mDataSetTypes.clear();
    mExample.clear();
    mSource.clear();*/
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return mDataSetTypes.get(position);


 }

}
```

My Logcat :

```
Process: com.roam1.roam1_selfcare, PID: 27679
                                                                      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                          at com.roam1.roam1_selfcare.InstructionAdapter.getItemViewType(InstructionAdapter.java:117)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4960)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1193)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1043)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1552)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2649)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9297)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2769)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9517)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                        at android
```

Comment: Can u post logcat?

Comment: I update my answer with logcat

Comment: Just a hunch:). Can u put mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in all the if conditions inside onCheckedChanged() and try

Comment: I tried ..but it ddnt work..it populate data perfectly, but when i scroll the screen , it crashes. I dont know, what is happening.

Comment: Please help me out..:(

Comment: Put a break point at getItemViewType() and tell me the size of mDataSetTypes?

Comment: Remove/comment the getItemViewType() for a while and try. Because you have only one view type.